# Setting default values for LaTeX3 keys

Tags: latex3, package-writing, package-options, l3keys

I've written the following code for setting values of a key as part of a package I'm working on, and for some odd reason the default doesn't seem to work. When the package this is part of is specified without any options, I'd expect `reset-question` to equal `section` and `reset-example` to equal `none`. Instead, both are set to `none`.

```
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-all .choice:,
  reset-all .default:n = false,
  reset-all / part .meta:n = {
    reset-question = part,
    reset-example = part
  },
  reset-all / chapter .meta:n = {
    reset-question = chapter,
    reset-example = chapter
  },
  reset-all / section .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = section
  },
  reset-all / subsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsection,
    reset-example = subsection
  },
  reset-all / subsubsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsubsection,
    reset-example = subsubsection
  },
  reset-all / paragraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = paragraph,
    reset-example = paragraph
  },
  reset-all / subparagraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subparagraph,
    reset-example = subparagraph
  },
  reset-all / false .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = none
  }
}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-question .default:n = section,
  reset-question .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{question}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-question / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{question}{section}
  },
}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-example .default:n = none,
  reset-example .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{example}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-example / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{example}{section}
  },
}
```

Commenting out the `reset-all` keys doesn't seem to have any effect on the default values of `reset-question` and `reset-example` either.

Here's a maximal working example to illustrate how this snippet will be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-all .choice:,
  reset-all .default:n = false,
  reset-all / part .meta:n = {
    reset-question = part,
    reset-example = part
  },
  reset-all / chapter .meta:n = {
    reset-question = chapter,
    reset-example = chapter
  },
  reset-all / section .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = section
  },
  reset-all / subsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsection,
    reset-example = subsection
  },
  reset-all / subsubsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsubsection,
    reset-example = subsubsection
  },
  reset-all / paragraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = paragraph,
    reset-example = paragraph
  },
  reset-all / subparagraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subparagraph,
    reset-example = subparagraph
  },
  reset-all / false .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = none
  }
}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-question .default:n = section,
  reset-question .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{question}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-question / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{question}{section}
  },
}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
  reset-example .default:n = none,
  reset-example .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{example}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-example / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{example}{section}
  },
}

\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{example}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { question } { s } {
  \par
  \IfBooleanTF #1
    { { \bfseries Question.\par } }
    {
      \refstepcounter{question}
      {\bfseries Question~\thequestion.\par}
    }
  \begin{itshape}
}
{\end{itshape}\par}
\cs_new:cpn {question*} {\question*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endquestion*} \endquestion
\NewDocumentEnvironment { example } { s } {
  \par
  \IfBooleanTF #1
    { { \bfseries Example.\par } }
    {
      \refstepcounter{example}
      {\bfseries Example~\theexample.\par}
    }
}
{\par}
\cs_new:cpn {example*} {\example*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endexample*} \endexample
\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttsetup{
  % reset-all = false,
  % reset-question = subsection,
  % reset-example = section,
}

\section{A section}

\begin{question}
The question in a section
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example*}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example*} environment.
\end{example*}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question*}
A starred question in a subsubsection
\end{question*}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}


\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\subsection{Another subsection}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What is this question?
\end{question}

\section{Another section}

\begin{question}
Another question in another section
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in another section
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I apologise for the huge length of these examples; I can try to trim them down if that would be more useful. The full code for this package is in a  [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zoqaeski/teachingtools).

Comment: I think I managed to fix this by adding a `\keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-all }` line right at the end of the package forcing that option to have its default value, which then propagates through the others.

Comment: You know the difference between `initial` and `default`, don't you?

Comment: I do now after finding `initial` in the manual. I really need to get into the habit of reading these manuals in full instead of just skimming to find out how to solve whatever task I'm working on next. Sometimes I think I'm too impatient to become a decent programmer.

Comment: @Robbie Unfortunately, I am guilty of the same habit, but reading `interface3` in full would require super-human ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've "fixed" your code in the following way: I've added the `initial` statement. You need to understand the difference: `.default` defines what happens when you do `\keys_set:nn {...} {mykey}` (what `mykey` should default to). `.initial` defines what should be the value of `mykey` at the beginning (initialization).

To achieve an `initial` value you need to define `reset-question` and `reset-example` before defining `reset-all`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{example}

\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    reset-question .default:n = section,
  reset-question .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{question}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-question / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{question}{section}
  },
  reset-example .default:n = none,
  reset-example .choices:nn = {
    part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
  }
  {
    \counterwithin*{example}{\l_keys_choice_tl}
  },
  reset-example / none .code:n = {
    \counterwithout*{example}{section}
  },
  reset-all .choice:,
  reset-all / part .meta:n = {
    reset-question = part,
    reset-example = part
  },
  reset-all / chapter .meta:n = {
    reset-question = chapter,
    reset-example = chapter
  },
  reset-all / section .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = section
  },
  reset-all / subsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsection,
    reset-example = subsection
  },
  reset-all / subsubsection .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subsubsection,
    reset-example = subsubsection
  },
  reset-all / paragraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = paragraph,
    reset-example = paragraph
  },
  reset-all / subparagraph .meta:n = {
    reset-question = subparagraph,
    reset-example = subparagraph
  },
  reset-all / false .meta:n = {
    reset-question = section,
    reset-example = none
  },
  reset-all .default:n = false,
  reset-all .initial:n = false,
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { question } { s } {
  \par
  \IfBooleanTF #1
    { { \bfseries Question.\par } }
    {
      \refstepcounter{question}
      {\bfseries Question~\thequestion.\par}
    }
  \begin{itshape}
}
{\end{itshape}\par}
\cs_new:cpn {question*} {\question*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endquestion*} \endquestion
\NewDocumentEnvironment { example } { s } {
  \par
  \IfBooleanTF #1
    { { \bfseries Example.\par } }
    {
      \refstepcounter{example}
      {\bfseries Example~\theexample.\par}
    }
}
{\par}
\cs_new:cpn {example*} {\example*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endexample*} \endexample
\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttsetup{
  % reset-all = false,
  % reset-question = subsection,
  % reset-example = section,
}

\section{A section}

\begin{question}
The question in a section
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example*}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example*} environment.
\end{example*}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question*}
A starred question in a subsubsection
\end{question*}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}


\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\subsection{Another subsection}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What is this question?
\end{question}

\section{Another section}

\begin{question}
Another question in another section
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in another section
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{example}
    This is an example of the \texttt{example} environment.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```